# Django Simple Email Confirmation App gives "Error 'User' object has no attribute 'get_primary_email'"

Tags: python, django, email

I'm trying to create an app that requires email confirmation (sending an email and requiring the click of a link within the email) for registration purposes. Unless I'm missing something, the simplest of methods appears to be the open source django app library "simple email confirmation." Source found [Here](https://github.com/mfogel/django-simple-email-confirmation). However, when I install the app and add the app to my settings.py, I get the following error when I try to use the python manage.py syncdb command to create my sqllite database. How can I resolve this, or please let me know if there is a more preferred method to do email confirmations in Django - I've searched extensively already. Thank you in advance.

```
 Error: 'User' object has no attribute 'get_primary_email'
```

Comment: Can you provide us a full trackback of your error.

Comment: Did you try taking step 3 of the installation document ("Add the provided mixin to your django 1.5+ custom user model")? https://github.com/mfogel/django-simple-email-confirmation

Comment: Are you using Django custom User?

Comment: Tanveer: The entire traceback is a bit too long to post in comments of this post. Here is a screenshot of it. Thanks for your help so far. http://imgur.com/s2uZncK

schneck: I did not. It said in the official documentation that it wasn't required, only recommended. Can you walk me through how to properly get the mixin working? I have never used mixins in django projects. 

David W: I am not. I assumed that was the issue as well, but I don't know how to create a custom User. I am using the basic User model from Django.Contrib.Auth module